# Why I'm getting these Errors - unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Tags: shell, eof

**Code**

```
 #! /bin/bash
    read -p "INterest " interest
    read -p "Enter loan " loan

    tot(){
        total=$( bc -l <<EOF
            scale=3
            $loan + $interest^3
            EOF
    )
        echo "$total"
    }

    tot
```

**output**
INterest 12
Enter loan 12
./eofp.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./eofp.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [here document](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) is terminated wrongly; either

1. start the here document with `<<-EOF` **and** indent using tabs or
2. put `EOF` on a line without any other characters.